# Remove duplicate results within one group Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

My SQL Stored Procedure returns following result:

```
ID  District  Decision
-----------------------
17  First     Approved
17  First     Partially approved
17  First     Pending
17  Second    Approved
17  Second    Partially approved
17  Second    Pending
```

The same was generated in my Crystal Reports. District and Decision columns have no any relationship. Both of them only related to ID (requestId). I'm getting duplicated results for each District as the result of joining 3 tables.
So far I was able to group records by ID and suppress duplicated rows. After doing so I've got following in my Report:

```
ID  District  Decision
-----------------------
17  First     Approved
              Partially approved
              Pending
    Second    Approved
              Partially approved
              Pending
```

So far so good, but what I eventually want is to get is something like follows:

```
ID  District  Decision
----------------------
17  First     Approved
    Second    Partially approved
              Pending
```

I want all blank spaces to be removed (which is left after suppressing duplicated) and leave only distinct records within ID group.

I want to do everything in Crystal Reports, that's why i'm excluding work around in the SQL server

Comment: F.Y.I. you can write your own SQL Commands *within* Crystal Reports. Just pop into the Database Expert, choose your connection, and pick Add Command.

Answer (score 0):

If editing the SQL isn't an option, you're on the right track. In short you'll want to:

1. Write a formula (`@YourFormula`) that evaluates True if the previous record has the same ID and District. (Hint: use the `PREVIOUS()` function.)
2. Format each field in your Details section such that the Suppression formula is set to `@YourFormula`.
3. In the Section Editor for Details, check "Suppress Blank Section".

This all hinges on whether or not your records are grouped correctly. If they sometimes appear out of order, you might need to edit your current SQL after all.

Comment: Thank you @4444 for your response. Something is not right. I followed the steps you explained, but i'm getting the same result. The formula i used is:    {usp_storedProcedure;1.ID} = 
    previous({usp_storedProcedure;1.ID})
AND {usp_storedProcedure;1.District} = 
    previous({usp_storedProcedure;1.District})

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose this without seeing/understanding your report. Are you opposed to writing a custom SQL Command within Crystal? That would give you a lot more control over what pulls into the report.

Comment: Sorry @4444 for late reply. I temporarily solved the problem with use of cursor in  stored procedure, but would be glad if you give me some clear example of how to use custom SQL command within Crystal!

Comment: Certainly - You basically add your SQL command as if it were another table in your database. Where you'd normally select a new table, click Add Command and write the SQL query there.